# Caffe HDF5 neural network basic example fails to parse the model file

Tags: caffe

I am trying to build a minimal example of a neural network with HDF5 data that I have prepared from a CSV file using the caffe libraries.

My prototext is as follows: [wine_train.prototxt]

```
name:"wineclass"
layers {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "examples/wine/test.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
  include{
   phase:TEST
  }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "label"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "examples/wine/train.txt"
    batch_size: 2
  }
  include{
   phase:TRAIN
  }
}
layers {
  name: "ip"
  type: "INNER_PRODUCT"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "ip"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 3
  }
}
layers {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SOFTMAX_LOSS"
  bottom: "ip"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "ip"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
}
```

and my solver is as follows:

```
net: "examples/wine/wine_train.prototxt"
test_iter: 250
test_interval: 1000
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 5000
display: 1000
max_iter: 10000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "wine/train"
solver_mode: CPU
```

Each time I get the following error:

```
shaunak@ubuntu:~/caffe$ build/tools/caffe train -model '/home/shaunak/caffe/examples/wine/wine_train.prototxt' -solver '/home/shaunak/caffe/examples/wine/solver.prototxt'
I0415 04:31:00.154145 57047 caffe.cpp:117] Use CPU.
I0415 04:31:00.154485 57047 caffe.cpp:121] Starting Optimization
I0415 04:31:00.154552 57047 solver.cpp:32] Initializing solver from parameters:
test_iter: 250
test_interval: 1000
base_lr: 0.01
display: 1000
max_iter: 10000
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
stepsize: 5000
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "wine/train"
solver_mode: CPU
net: "examples/wine/wine_train.prototxt"
I0415 04:31:00.154660 57047 solver.cpp:70] Creating training net from net file: examples/wine/wine_train.prototxt
[libprotobuf ERROR google/protobuf/text_format.cc:245] Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 4:9: Expected integer or identifier.
F0415 04:31:00.154774 57047 upgrade_proto.cpp:928] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: examples/wine/wine_train.prototxt
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f4a30766c3c  google::LogMessage::Fail()
    @     0x7f4a30766b88  google::LogMessage::SendToLog()
    @     0x7f4a3076658a  google::LogMessage::Flush()
    @     0x7f4a30769521  google::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()
    @     0x7f4a30b8b1ee  caffe::ReadNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie()
    @     0x7f4a30b6dfa2  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7f4a30b6ee63  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7f4a30b6f036  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @           0x40c3c0  caffe::GetSolver<>()
    @           0x406361  train()
    @           0x4048f1  main
    @     0x7f4a2fe86ec5  (unknown)
    @           0x404e9d  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
shaunak@ubuntu:~/caffe$
```

What exactly does the error say and how do I resolve it?

## Update

This seems to run:

```
name: "WineNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "wine_train_data"
  top: "wine_train_label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "examples/wine/train.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "wine_train_data"
  top: "fc1"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 2
    }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc1"
  bottom: "wine_train_label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

### UPDATE2

Virtually identical models: One works the other doesn't. I cant explain why!

Works:

```
name: "WineNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "wine_train_data"
  top: "wine_train_label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "examples/wine/train.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "wine_train_data"
  top: "fc1"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 2
    }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc1"
  bottom: "wine_train_label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Doesn't:

```
name:"wineclass"
layers {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "wine_train_data"
  top: "wine_train_label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "examples/wine/train.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
}
layer {
  name: "ip"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "wine_train_data"
  top: "ip"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 2
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "ip"
  bottom: "wine_train_label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problem yesterday. You might need to check that your caffe version is up-to-date. They changed the protobuf definition quite heavily. In your case, "type" used to be an enum, now it just takes a string.

***[Update]*** From the discussion in the comments: The answer is to not use "layers" but "layer". layers was probably present in some old / outdated example.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. This one sees to run:
name: "WineNet"
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "wine_train_data"
  top: "wine_train_label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "examples/wine/train.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
}
layer {
  name: "fc1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "wine_train_data"
  top: "fc1"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 2
 }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "fc1"
  bottom: "wine_train_label"
  top: "loss"
}

Comment: updated the answer with a working example. I think I have set all type parameters to string. 

Also my build is less than a week old. Still I will update it in the evening.

Comment: Ok, I just installed caffe yesterday (but via a Docker image, thats why it was out of date), so I'm not sure when this was added. But the error is the same.

Comment: Now you're using "layers" and "layer" in the one that does'nt work. Try sticking to "layer", I got that wrong as well. @shaunakde

Comment: Please add that to your answer, or perhaps I shall edit it? Thanks!